# Why can't i display the returned image using queue

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv

I am trying to capture a frame from the webcam with the help of a thread, and then returning it through a queue. When I run the code, I get the return type as a np.array but when I display it I get a callback warning and not output.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
import queue
import threading

def capture(out_queue):
  while(True):
     frame = cap.read()[1]
     cv2.imshow('window', frame)
     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        out_queue.put(frame)
        break

my_queue_1 = queue.Queue()
t1 = threading.Thread(target=capture, args=(my_queue_1,))
t1.start()
t1.join()
ret1 = my_queue_1.get()
print(type(ret1))
cv2.imshow('returned', ret1)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cap.release()
```

I get the type as class 'numpy.ndarray' & 
[ WARN:0] terminating async callback

Comment: could you add the stacktrace please

Comment: I'm not sure I can verbalise the situation exactly, but my experience is that OpenCV *"is picky about having multiple threads accessing the screen and keyboard"*. I think `cv2.imshow()` is not thread-safe, so I have tended to do all display and keyboard interactions from a single thread. Hopefully someone else will nail down the limitations (or correct me wholesale) so we all learn.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: forgot to include cv2.waitkey(). problem solved